# Will only read and write one line

Tags: java, android, input, local-storage, fileoutputstream

Program runs fine however I can not figure out why it will only read and write one line. It should be able to write multiple lines and read them into the textview. I have it setup so that when the user clicks add it automatically should read into the textview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText Activity, Miles, Date;
TextView Log;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Activity = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editText));
    Miles = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editText2));
    Date = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.editText3));
    Log = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.textView));
}
public void Add(View view)
{
    String Myactivity = Activity.getText().toString() + "\t" +   Miles.getText().toString() + "\t" + Date.getText().toString();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  openFileOutput("myActivities.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(Myactivity.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activty Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("myActivities.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String action;
        while((action = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
        {
            stringBuffer.append(action + "\n");
        }
        Log.setText(stringBuffer.toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }


}
```

}

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="mbl404.phoenix.edu.week2appgk5343.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Please Enter Type of Workout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:hint="Please Enter Number of Miles"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:hint="Please Enter Date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="Add"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: edit your question and show layout.activity_main.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `textview` xml

```
   android:maxLines="100"
```

**In your code:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:maxLines="100" <!-- add android:maxLines to specify the number of lines in textview -->
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**Updated:**

```
    while((action = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
    {
        Log.setText(Log.getText() + action + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: added that but it still replaces the current line with a the new line. Does not add another line

Comment: I updated my answer please check this and response to me

Comment: That code did not work. However it gave me an idea  stringBuffer.append(Log.getText().toString() + action + "\n"); this works perfectly

Comment: yes. and android:maxLines="100" actually does the magic. because it allows textview to display more than one lines.